# How can I get my notes from the Pegasus notemaker pen?

Tags: notes

I've just bought my notemaker, an electronic pen from http://www.pegatech.com/ and wonder If I can download notes on Ubuntu.

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consult Google before asking here?

I ask that because on my very first Google search, this relevant looking result was second on the results page.

http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/m210-59695.shtml

Comment: Wow! Thank you! The only query I tried with Google was **Ritmix ubuntu** and no results were found. I came here to ask and then realized, that a pen name may vary upon the country and I googled the right name. But not googled for linux solution with the right name. Sorry :)

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is trying different search terms :) I Googled 'pegasys notemaker ubuntu' to get that result.